# Using native dlls in Windows Store application

Tags: windows, dll, native

I need to use native dlls in Windows Store app.
(dlls are ffmpeg, compiled for Windows)

Is it possible?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/b395e4ec-915a-46b7-81c4-6ff23cfa9c4b/

Comment: The odds you'll get ffmpeg through the Store validator are very low.  Pretty sure it uses too many forbidden winapi functions, like LoadLibrary and CreateFile.

Comment: Cannot open your link. :-( Please, tell me, where i can find a list of forbidden WinAPI funcs for Windows Store?